# What is the difference between "Kill App" and "Force Stop" android application?

Tags: android

In my device, in a task killer application I get both options either to "kill" the app or "Force Stop" it. What exactly is the difference between these two?

Comment: What task killer application are you using? Probably "kill" sends "KILL" signal to the app while "Force Stop" sends "TERM" signal, vice versa. The process can refuse to stop if "TERM" is received based on its current status, but "KILL" will kill the process for sure.