# difference between swipe kill the app and force stop related to Application class

Tags: android

I have an application that implements the `Application` class.

consider the following 2 scenarios:

A) open the application -> press home -> long-press home to see recent apps. -> swipe kill the application. in this case, the `Application` class `onCreate` function will be called without any interaction.

B)open the application -> press home -> long press on the app -> viw app info -> click on force stop. in this case, the `Application` class `onCreate` function will NOT be called.

My questions are:

1 - what is the difference between the two scenarios related to the `Application` life cycle.

2- Why when I swipe kill the app the `Application` `onCreate` method gets called?

P.S I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974746/what-is-the-difference-between-kill-app-and-force-stop-android-application) and it doesn't answer my question.

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that this behavior in scenario A is not the same for all devices. for example, it happens on a Samsung phone but not on a Pixel phone. maybe it's up to the manufacturer?

picture for scenario A:
[image]
picture for scenario B:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter what are the differenece... If you wana know this: a) you just wana know just for knowing b) you wana do something terrible against lifecycle of the app

Comment: I have some code that runs inside the `onCreate` of the `Application` class. I want to understand if it can get called multiple times and when.

Answer (score 5):

- When you swipe the app, you kill only activity components. If there are any background services, they will continue working.
- When you force stop the app from app menu, you switch off all services working background. For example you will not receive push notifications after this action.

Comment: Does this mean that my application would still have memory?

Comment: If you force stop app RAM processes will be cleaned

Comment: How do I force stop app RAM?

Comment: You mean programmatically? Can you improve your question?